# "KeyError: in converted code" when packing data with numeric features in Tensorflow Tutorial

Tags: tensorflow, python-3.7, tensorflow-datasets, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-estimator

I'm using TF 2.0 on Google Colab. I copied from of the most code the Tensorflow "Load CSV Data" tutorial and changed up some config variables for my training and eval / test csv files. When I ran it, I got this error (only last frame is shown, full output is [here](https://pastebin.com/psdrBB2S):

In

```
NUMERIC_FEATURES = ['microtime', 'dist']

packed_train_data = raw_train_data.map(
    PackNumericFeatures(NUMERIC_FEATURES))

packed_test_data = raw_test_data.map(
    PackNumericFeatures(NUMERIC_FEATURES))
```

Out

```
/tensorflow-2.0.0/python3.6/tensorflow_core/python/autograph/impl/api.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    235       except Exception as e:  # pylint:disable=broad-except
    236         if hasattr(e, 'ag_error_metadata'):
--> 237           raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
    238         else:
    239           raise

KeyError: in converted code:

    <ipython-input-19-85ea56f80c91>:6 __call__  *
        numeric_features = [features.pop(name) for name in self.names]
    /tensorflow-2.0.0/python3.6/tensorflow_core/python/autograph/impl/api.py:396 converted_call
        return py_builtins.overload_of(f)(*args)

    KeyError: 'dist'
```

Answer (score 0):

The "in converted code" is used when autograph wraps errors that likely occur in user code. In this case, the following like is relevant:

```
    <ipython-input-19-85ea56f80c91>:6 __call__  *
        numeric_features = [features.pop(name) for name in self.names]
```

The error message is missing some critical information and we should fix it, but it suggests a call to `features.pop(name)` raises `KeyError`, so likely that key is missing from `features`.